# Microsoft graph table api not returning column values in its date format

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, excel-2010

I'm retrieving data from Microsoft workbook/excel file's table.
Workbook's table has date-of-birth column which has date format.
While retrieving values using Microsoft graph's table api it returns dates as some integer value.

API i'm using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/book.xlsx:/workbook/tables/table4/columns
```

Microsoft graph API reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-list-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('<user_id>')/drive/root/workbook/tables('table4')/columns",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.id": "/users('<user_id>')/drive/root/workbook/tables(%27%7BF44C7573-9BBE-46F3-B0BE-C5607762D2AB%7D%27)/columns(%271%27)",
        "values": [
            [
                "Name"
            ],
            [
                "Student 1"
            ],
            [
                "Student 2"
            ]
        ],
        "id": "1",
        "index": 0,
        "name": "Name"
    },
    {
        "@odata.id": "/users('<user_id>')/drive/root/workbook/tables(%27%7BF44C7573-9BBE-46F3-B0BE-C5607762D2AB%7D%27)/columns(%273%27)",
        "values": [
            [
                "DOB"
            ],
            [
                35339
            ],
            [
                34249
            ]
        ],
        "id": "3",
        "index": 1,
        "name": "DOB"
    }
 ]
}
```

**Original values are**
[image]

Is there any way to get date values in its original format

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with *java*?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you are using

```
GET /me/drive/root:/book.xlsx:/workbook/tables/table4/columns
```

returns [workbookTableColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/workbooktablecolumn?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource type which has only information about raw values without information about data type and formatting.

You can use `id` or `name` of `workbookTableColumn` and call [dataBodyRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tablecolumn-databodyrange?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint

```
GET /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns/{columnId|columnName}/dataBodyRange
GET /me/drive/root:/book.xlsx:/workbook/tables/{id|name}/columns/{columnId|columnName}/dataBodyRange
```

which returns [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/range?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource type.

`Range` resource type has property `text` which represents text values of the specified range.

```
...
"text": [
    [
        "09.06.2022"
    ],
    [
        ""
    ]
],
...
```

Comment: Here column names would be dynamic in file.
With this approach I have to perform call for all columns of the table.

Comment: Columns name is not available in the response of  https: //graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/book.xlsx:/workbook/tables/table4/dataBodyRange

Comment: @HarshadPanmand If column names are dynamic, you can still use id (column index) but you are right that you have to perform more than one call to get data you need.